# HashTable of Array of LinkList

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

im trying to make a linked list of generic objects. i have the linked list made now i have to load a file of movies(in movie class i have genre,rating, title).first i need to load a CVS file of movies the create Hash Table Object which contains an array of Linked List objects which in turn stores the Movies. so for example in a movie class i will have genre and genre can be many. i want to get hash code of genre and then store that in a hash table of arrayed linked list. that's what im using the LoadingMovie class for.

i dont know what im doing as it my first time working with hash tables and link list etc.this is what i have so far:

```
    public class List<T> {
    private Node<T> head;

    private Node<T> tail;
    private int count;

    public void append(T d) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = tail = new Node<T>(d);
        } else {
            tail.insertAfter(d);
            tail = tail.getNext();
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void prepend(T d) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = tail = new Node<T>(d);
        } else {
            head.insertBefore(d);

            head = head.getPrevious();

            count++;
        }
    }

    public void removeHead() {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        } else if (head == tail) {
            head = tail = null;
            count--;
            return;
        }
        head = head.getNext();
        count--;
    }

    public ListIterator<T> getIterator() {
        return new ListIterator<T>(this, head);
    }

    public void add(ListIterator<T> iter, T data) {
        if (iter.getList() != this) {
            return;
        }
        if (!iter.isValid()) {
            append(data);
        } else {
            iter.getCurrentNode().insertAfter(data);
            count++;
            if (iter.getCurrentNode() == tail) {
                tail = iter.getCurrentNode().getNext();
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(ListIterator<T> iter) {
        if (iter.getList() != this) {
            return;
        }
        Node<T> node = iter.getCurrentNode();
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        } else if (node == head) {
            removeHead();
        } else if (node == tail) {
            removeTail();
        } else {
            Node<T> ptn = node.getPrevious();
            ptn.setNext(node.getNext());
            node.getNext().setPrevious(ptn);
            iter.advance();
            count--;
        }
    }

    public void removeTail() {
        if (head == null) {

        } else if (head == tail) {
            head = tail = null;
            count--;
        } else {
            Node<T> node = head;
            while (node.getNext() != tail) {
                node = node.getNext();

            }

            tail = node;
            tail.setNext(null);
            count--;

        }
    }

    public void display() {
        ListIterator<T> iter = getIterator();

        do {
            System.out.println(iter.item()+ " , ");
            iter.advance();
        } while (iter.isValid());
    }

    public void displayReverse() {
        ListIterator<T> iter = getIterator();
        iter.end();

        do {
            System.out.print(iter.item() + " , ");
            iter.previous();
        } while (iter.isValid());
    }


    public Node<T> getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public Node<T> getTail() {
        return tail;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setHead(Node<T> head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void setTail(Node<T> tail) {
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.head);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.tail);
        hash = 89 * hash + this.count;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final List<?> other = (List<?>) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.head, other.head)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.tail, other.tail)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.count != other.count) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

this is the node class :

    public class Node<T> {

    T anElement;
    Node<T> next;
    Node<T> previous;

    public Node() {
        anElement = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(T elem) {
        anElement = elem;
        next = null;
    }

    public T getAnElement() {
        return anElement;
    }

    public void setAnElement(T anElement) {
        this.anElement = anElement;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node<T> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Node<T> previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyNode{" + "anElement=" + anElement + ", next=" + next + '}';
    }

    public void insertAfter(T nextData) {
        if (nextData == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node s = new Node(nextData);
        s.setNext(next);
        s.setPrevious(this);
        if (next != null) {
            next.setPrevious(s);
        }

        next = s;

    }

    public void insertBefore(T data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node s = new Node(data);
        s.setNext(this);
        s.setPrevious(previous);

        if (previous != null) {
            previous.setNext(s);
        }

        previous = s;

    }

}

this is the load file class :

    public class LoadingMovies {

    private static final int size = 127;
    private static HashMap<String, Movies> hash = new HashMap(size);
    public static void loadMovies(String filename) {
        String split = ","; //split with comma

        try {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            String wordIn;


            //List<Movies> linked = new List<>();

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                wordIn = in.nextLine();
                String splitter[] = wordIn.split(split);

                String movieTitle = splitter[0];
                String movieGenre = splitter[1];
                String ageRating = splitter[2];
                double scoreRating = Double.parseDouble(splitter[3]);

                Movies movie = new Movies();
                movie.setTitle(movieTitle);
                movie.setGenre(movieGenre);
                movie.setAgeRating(ageRating);
                movie.setScoreRating(scoreRating);

                hash.find(movie.getGenre()); 
                hash.insert(movie.getGenre(), movie);
                hash.display();

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured in the loadMovies() method in the Loadingovies class");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String filename = input.next();
        loadMovies(filename);
    }

this is the hash map method:

    public class HashMap<KeyType,DataType>
{
    private int count;
    private int size;
    private List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> [] table;

    public HashMap() {
    }

    public HashMap(int num)
    {
        size = num;
        table = new List[num];
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            table[i] = new List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>>();
        }
    }

    public void insert(KeyType key, DataType data){
        if(key != null && data != null){
            int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
            HashEntry<KeyType, DataType> obj = new HashEntry(key, data);
            table[hash].append(obj);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void display(){
      for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
          System.out.println("tables" + i + " ");
          table[i].display();
      }
    }

    public DataType find(KeyType key){
        int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
        List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> list = table[hash];
        ListIterator <HashEntry<KeyType, DataType>> iter = list.getIterator();

        while(iter.isValid()){
            if(iter.item().getKey().equals(key)){
                return iter.item().getData();
            }
            iter.advance();
        }
        return null;
    }

   public void remove(KeyType key){
        int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
        List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> list = table[hash];
        ListIterator <HashEntry<KeyType, DataType>> iter = list.getIterator();

        while(iter.isValid()){
            if(iter.item().getKey().equals(key)){
                list.remove(iter);
            }
            iter.advance();
        }
    }
}

and this is what i have for movie class:

    public class Movies {

    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String ageRating;
    private double scoreRating;

    public Movies() {
        title = "";
        genre = "";
        ageRating = "";
        scoreRating = 0;
    }

    public Movies(String title, String genre, String ageRating, double scoreRating) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.ageRating = ageRating;
        this.scoreRating = scoreRating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getAgeRating() {
        return ageRating;
    }

    public double getScoreRating() {
        return scoreRating;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setAgeRating(String ageRating) {
        this.ageRating = ageRating;
    }

    public void setScoreRating(double scoreRating) {
        this.scoreRating = scoreRating;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Movies other = (Movies) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.title, other.title)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.genre, other.genre)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.ageRating, other.ageRating)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.scoreRating) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.scoreRating)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 11;

        hash = (int) ((hash * 10) + scoreRating);

        if (this.title != null) {
            hash = (hash * 10) + title.hashCode();
        }
        if (this.genre != null) {
            hash = (hash * 10) + genre.hashCode();
        }
        if (this.ageRating != null) {
            hash = (hash * 10) + ageRating.hashCode();
        }

        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String statement = "Movie Title:" + title + "\n" + "Movie Genre:" + genre + "\n" + "Age Rating: " + ageRating + "\n" + "User Score: " + scoreRating + "\n";
        return statement;
    }
```

what am i doing wrong please :(
i get null pointer exceptions arrayoutofboundexceptions
some movies printing and i get loads of tables thatare null :'(

Comment: Hey . you have a lot of code here. Can you point to the problematic part? share the stack?

Comment: And... you *know* there's a LinkedList in java.util, right?

Comment: This kind of question is more appropriate to Code Review. Consider posting there instead. ;) Also, make sure you polish your text because it is unclear *what* your problem is.

Comment: yea its my first time using stack overflow sorry.

Comment: @user244255 No, this question would be closed as broken code on Code Review. It's off-topic there.

Comment: Okay, scratch what I said then, but refine the text to better communicate what you want, author.

Comment: im trying to add the movie object loaded in the load movie class and create a hashTable of array of linklist. so for example if i have 5 genres i was to get the hashcode of the genres and place then in seperate location in the linked list and then every other movies with the same genre (same hashcode) will be stored in the same array

Comment: im cant use the linklist in util. have to work with datastructure and how it works etc

Comment: help i still cant see whats wrong. :(

Comment: Can you describe a specific problem you're seeing? Like, under what circumstances are you getting an NPE? Right off the bat there are some specific issues with your implementation of hashcode but I'm not sure that's the problem. Also, it's possible there's a bug in your ListIterator implementation for empty lists (i.e. head == tail == null).

Comment: @sisyphus when i run `LoadingMovies` class get a lot of empty tables and nothig being viewed and i dont know why. and i dont think there any bugs etc. how would u get the amount of genres in a file and get their hashcode then placed those in a array of linklist? :(

Comment: You probably have empty tables because your hashtables aren't full. If you have fewer than 127 rows in your data file then you're bound to have at least one empty bucket.

Comment: @sisyphus [http://www.dkit.derekflood.com/GetMovies.php]. This is where im getting a hundred row of movies from. And i want to load it then store in a array of link list. But i need to find out how many genres there are then array of link list for each genre and place movies with same hash code for genre.how can i do this and what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in mapping objects to buckets. This line of code...

```
int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
```

is capable of producing a negative value. key.hashCode() can be a negative number, and the result of the % operator on a negative number is a negative number. That's what causes your ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. The simplest solution is to use the absolute value of the hashCode...

```
int hash = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size;
```